# textbox click event not fired on fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using jquery [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/) in my asp.net MVC application like this:

```
 $.fancybox.open([$("#AddCallRecordingPopup")], {
                            helpers: {
                                width: 600,
                                title: null,
                                autoHeight: true,
                                overlay: {
                                    css: {
                                        cursor: 'auto'
                                    },
                                    closeClick: false
                                }
                            }

                        });
```

and I can see the fancybox. Html for fancybox is:

```
                    <div id="AddCallRecordingPopup" title="Add Call Recording" style="display: none"
            class="popup-dv">           
 <input type="text" value="" title="Click here to enter a telephone number" name="NumberCalledTo" id="NumberCalledTo" class="normal phone required" autocomplete="off">
 </div>
```

I am trying to use below js to fire click event on textbox which is on fancybox

```
 var $inputs = $(".phone"), $selects = $('.dialprefix');  

    $inputs.click(function () {
        /* get index of active input and use to match select*/
        var idx = $inputs.index(this), $sel = $selects.eq(idx);
        var dialprefix = $sel.val();
        var Id = $sel.attr('id');

        $(this).focus();
        var phone = $(this).val();
        var phoneId = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#PhoneNumber").val(phone);
        $("#SelecteddialprefixId").val(Id);
        $("#SelectedPhoneId").val(phoneId);

    })
```

but I am getting :

```
TypeError: element.prop(...) is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

rez  = element.prop('class').match(/fancybox\.(\w+)/);
```

This happens only when I click the textbox. Fancybox closes and I see the error. I think there is some jquery clash with fancybox on $inputs.click. Please suggest solution to it.